# Materialize: modal shifts background and causes page jumping right

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog, materialize

When opening modals, sidenav or data picker in Materialize CSS, the whole page is jumping right, because scrollbar is disappearing.

http://materializecss.com/modals.html

How I can prevent it?

Comment: They're probably going to close this question because of it being so broad, but I will give you this tip. Look into PrettyScroll.js The problem with the regular browser scroll is that it pushes the viewport so that it can use the space. But pretty scroll floats over the viewport. No movement at all

Comment: After you include pretty scroll or any other version of it, if something went wrong, come here with the specific problem, and code snippet and ask a direct question ;)

Answer (score 2):

On carefully inspecting that link in your question.....You may want to put 
`overflow: auto !important;` to your html `<body>` tag css styling (quick hack)

example

```
body {
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    overflow: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this should fix the issue

```
body {
   padding: 0 !important
}
```